# How to properly erase an element from a React state array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management, react-state

Creating components based on a state-array and giving each component a setState attribute to the array leads to strange behavior. Maybe due to parallel state changes? Try out the snippet below. Clicking on a square should delete it. Instead always the last square created will be deleted.

The problem seems to lie in the `useEffect()` within the `Square` component. While in the snippet it's really not useful, I use something like that to make the elements draggable. Can someone explain this behavior and suggest a solution? I feel like I missed something important about React here.

```js
function Square(props){
  const [pos, setPos] = React.useState([props.top, props.left])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    props.setSquares(prevState => prevState.map((square, index) => index === props.index ? {...square, top: pos + 20} : square
    ))
  }, [pos])

  function deleteMe(){
    props.setSquares(prevState => prevState.filter((square, index) => index !== props.index))
  }

  return <div onClick={deleteMe} 
    style={{top: pos[0]+'px', left: pos[1]+'px'}}             
    className='square'>
  </div>
}

function App(){
  const [squares, setSquares] = React.useState([
    {top: 20, left: 0},{top: 20, left: 100},
    {top: 20, left: 200},{top: 20, left: 300}])

  React.useEffect(() => console.log('rerender', ...squares.map(s => s.left)))

  return <div>{squares.map((square, index) => <Square 
    setSquares={setSquares} index={index} 
    top={square.top} left={square.left}/>)}</div>
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.square{
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id='root'></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**Edit:** As Nick suggested in the comments, I changed the `setSquare` methods to use `prevState.map` and `filter` in order to not change the previous state involuntarily.

The problem remains though... always the last square vanishes on screen. Using an effect on each re-render shows that the state gets updated correctly. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that the spread operator is a *shallow* copy, meaning `newSquares[props.index].top = pos[0] + 20` in the following code is mutating an object in your current state array.

```
props.setSquares(prevState => {
  const newSquares = [...prevState]
  newSquares[props.index].top = pos[0] + 20 // this is mutating current state
  return newSquares
})
```

One option to fix this is to do this instead:

```
props.setSquares(prevState => {
  const newSquares = [...prevState]
  newSquares[props.index] = { 
    ...newSquares[props.index],
    top: pos[0] + 20
  };
  return newSquares
})
```

Another option is to just map over your existing state and just return something new for the element you want to change:

```
props.setSquares(prevState => {
  return prevState.map((el, i) => {
    return i === props.index ? { ...el, top: pos[0] + 20 } : el;
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I assumed a shallow copy wouldn't be harmful because it happens inside the `setSquares` method where `prevState` is only a local variable, right? Messing with `prevState` here shouldn't have an effect on the current state. Also a proper copy (eg produced by `map`) leads to the same behavior.
While a `console.log(squares)` right before `App`s return shows that the correct square was deleted from state, on screen the wrong one vanished

Comment: I don't believe `prevState` is a deep copy of the state object even in a callback function--fairly certain that would be super inefficient.

Comment: I think you're conflating reassignment and mutation in this example. A more apt example would be if you state was an object and you were mutating a property of that object

Comment: You are absolutely right about that of course. I changed the [codepen](https://codepen.io/wutzig/pen/rNaPWaa) a bit. I'm still fairly convinced that one can't mess with `prevState` within a `setState`.

Comment: The problem with `prevState` somehow being independent of the current state means React would have to be doing a deep copy under the hood, which would be very inefficient since _every_ component that relies on a piece of your state would then re-render

Comment: you were absolutely right about the role of `prevState`. Changing the previous state and returning a shallow copy does change the state, there is just no rerender taking place. That's why it seems like nothing changes. The weird behavior still remains though.